# Performance: Google Dataflow writes avro file to GCS

Tags: java, apache-beam, dataflow

I am working on Google Dataflow which pulls data from pubsub, converts to avro, and writes them to GCS.
According to the monitoring page, the bottleneck is writing avro file to GCS (spending 70-80 % of total execution time).

I use

- 10 workers of n1-standard-8
- 10 numShards
- 5sec fixedwindow
- The region of GCS and Dataflow endpoint is same.

Then the performance is around 200,000 elements per second.
Is it fast on this situation or is there anything I can do to make it faster? (I really want to!)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered naming your files following a [specific convention](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-rate#naming-convention) in order to optimize access read and write ?

> In order to maintain a high request rate, avoid using sequential names. Using completely random object names will give you the best load distribution. If you want to use sequential numbers or timestamps as part of your object names, introduce randomness to the object names by adding a hash value before the sequence number or timestamp.

Basically you need to follow the same rules as choosing a RowKey in BigTable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) I tried as the GSC document says (put md4 hash to the head of filename). but the performance did not change and the share of the total execution time stays same. and I talked with a person using almost same workflow and that performance is almost same I face, so maybe this is the limit...